# Adjust table row height to fill 100% of the table no matter how many rows

Tags: html, css

I have a table that will have either 3 or 4 rows and I want the table to to be a set height of 280px.

Is there a way to get the height of the rows to fill the table height depending on how many rows are in the table?

To make it clearer, if the table has 3 rows, each row will be about 33% height and if the table has 4 rows, each row will be 25% height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in plain css.
Just specify the height of the parent div to 280px, and the height of table to 100%.

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 280px;
}

.tableElem{
  height: 100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <table class="tableElem">
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<br /><br /><br />

<div id="wrapper">
  <table class="tableElem">
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)

Comment: Good, @MarcUy but I'm still confused for different content. If there are different content in `<td>` having different heights, will the height remains same?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have done it with jquery .

Hope it will be helpful

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var rowCount = $('.countRow tr').length;
  a=280/rowCount;
  $('.countRow tr').css('height',a)
})
```

```css
div{height:280px; background:#ccc;}
table{border:1px solid #777; border-collapse:collapse;}
td{border:1px solid #777; border-collapse:collapse;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> 
  <table class="countRow">
  <tr>
  <td>dsadasdA</td><td>ASSasAS</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>dsadasdA</td><td>ASSasAS</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>dsadasdA</td><td>ASSasAS</td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>dsadasdA</td><td>ASSasAS</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what **Marc Uy**, I'm talking about. Please take a look.

```js
function adjustRow() {
  var getRow = document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('td');
  var max = -1;

  for (i = 0; i < getRow.length; i++) {
    var getHeight = getRow[i].clientHeight;
    max = getHeight > max ? getHeight : max;
  }

  for (j = 0; j < getRow.length; j++) {
    getRow[j].style.height = max + 'px';
  }
}

adjustRow();
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
}
tr {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      normal
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      normal
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      having different height
      <br>having different height
      <br>having different height
      <br>having different height
      <br>having different height
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```